# Invalid SQL result in INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join, native-sql

I have the following db (SQL Server) structure:

```
CREATE TABLE MASTER
(
    ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    NAME varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS varchar(200) NULL
)
;

CREATE TABLE CONNECTOR
(
    ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    CODE varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    MASTER_ID uniqueidentifier NULL
)
;

ALTER TABLE MASTER
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MASTER
    PRIMARY KEY (ID ASC)
;

ALTER TABLE CONNECTOR
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CONNECTOR_MASTER
    PRIMARY KEY (ID ASC)
;

ALTER TABLE CONNECTOR ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CONNECTOR_MASTER
    FOREIGN KEY (MASTER_ID) REFERENCES MASTER (ID) ON DELETE No Action ON UPDATE No Action
;
```

This is the set MASTER table:

```
ID                                     NAME ADDRESS
11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001    N1  A1
11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000002    N2  A2
11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000003    N3  A3
```

This is the set of CONNECTOR table:

```
ID                                     CODE MASTER_ID
22222222-1111-0000-0000-000000000001    X   11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001
22222222-1111-0000-0000-000000000002    Y   11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001
22222222-1111-0000-0000-000000000003    X   11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000002
22222222-1111-0000-0000-000000000004    W   11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000002
22222222-1111-0000-0000-000000000005    U   11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000003
```

This is my query:

```
select * 
    from test.dbo.MASTER m
    inner join test.dbo.CONNECTOR c ON c.MASTER_ID=m.ID 
    where 'X' IN (select c2.CODE from CONNECTOR c2 where MASTER_ID='11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001');
```

And this is my result:
(MASTER.ID, MASTER.NAME, MASTER.ADDRESS, CONNECTOR.ID, CONNECTOR.MASTER_ID)

```
11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001    N1  A1  22222222-1111-0000-0000-000000000001    X   11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001
11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001    N1  A1  22222222-1111-0000-0000-000000000002    Y   11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001
11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000002    N2  A2  22222222-1111-0000-0000-000000000003    X   11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000002
11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000002    N2  A2  22222222-1111-0000-0000-000000000004    W   11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000002
11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000003    N3  A3  22222222-1111-0000-0000-000000000005    U   11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000003
```

My Question is: Why? I am expecting only one row, this one:

```
11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001    N1  A1  22222222-1111-0000-0000-000000000001    X   11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001
```

Comment: `'X' IN (select...` will be true for all rows.

Comment: Could you pls. elaborate this why?

Comment: If you execute the subquery alone, you will find an X is returned.

Comment: `where 'X' IN (select c2.CODE from CONNECTOR c2 where MASTER_ID='11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001');` <--- This WHERE condition has no relationship to the tables in your `FROM` clause. It's like saying `WHERE 1=1`. Instead you probably just want `WHERE c.code = 'X' AND c.MASTER_ID = '11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001'`

Answer (score 1):

Your where clause is checking if `'X'` is in the subquery, and it is, so this resolves to `where true` and returns all rows.

Answer (score 1):

You sub query

```
select c2.Code from Connector c2 where Master_id='11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001'
```

returns two rows of result

[image]

To get the one row result probably you need to change your where condition like

```
select * 
from test.master m
inner join test.Connector  c ON c.Master_id=m.ID 
where c.code='X' and c.Master_id='11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001'
```

This query + will give only the expected output.

[image]

Anyway try this and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You used a conditional,

```
'X' IN (select c2.CODE from CONNECTOR c2 
where MASTER_ID='11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001');
```

if result of subquery is X (similar x=x is True). ignore conditional subquery and use  only Top join

```
select * 
 from test.dbo.MASTER m
inner join test.dbo.CONNECTOR c ON c.MASTER_ID=m.ID
```

else
if result of subquery is not x (similar x!=other thing(c,b,..) is False). ignore join Top and Result is empty

If you want to your expected, you must use this code

```
select * 
    from dbo.MASTER m
    inner join  (
            select c2.CODE,MASTER_ID from CONNECTOR c2 
            where MASTER_ID='11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001'
            and c2.CODE='X'
    )c ON c.MASTER_ID=m.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the condition on `MASTER_ID` and `code` on the join condition :

```
SELECT * 
from MASTER m
inner join CONNECTOR c ON c.MASTER_ID=m.ID 
                       and c.code = 'X' and c.MASTER_ID='11111111-1111-0000-0000-000000000001'
```